# How to open/load 3d image in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hello Friends I want to know is there any way we can open or load any 3d image in android,basically if we talk only about android according my knowledge its not possbile(not supported) so need to use opengles.however I know basic things in opengles also have made triangle and rectangle in 3d mode but suppose if i want to show any prebulit 3d image in it how to do it? OR how to make 3d image in android itself.Kindly share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to draw 3D images on Android is OpenGL.  There's OpenGL ES and OpenGL ES 2.0.  In addition, if you want to get really fancy you can check out tools like Unity that can create 3D worlds on Android.

References:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html
http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/android.html

Comment: Thank you spatulamania for your reply I know opengles little bit,but not have any idea for unity tool I will definately check it, if you have any useful links then share it thanx

Comment: @RoshanJha Here's the best place I know of for getting started with Unity: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12321/how-can-i-start-learning-unity-fast-list-of-tutori.html

Comment: Spatulamania,is there any other tool for making 3d game(or like loading 3d image as I aksed) apart from opengles and unity 3d,just want to know whether I have more option or I must deal with these two only.

Comment: @RoshanJha What is the format of your 3D image?  Can you display it in a standard image view?

Comment: Spatulamania,is format matters?As in opengles i can draw 2d rectangle and 3d cube,same way want to make or load any of 3d image.just want to know only unity3d and opengles is solution?

Comment: @RoshanJha There may be other tools but even Unity uses open GL.  The two options are OpenGL ES and OpenGL es 2.0.